# Use an equation to add number either to cell A1,A2 or A3 depending on a combination of IF statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spread sheet used for Cash Flow projections and hence multiple income streams.  The Cash Flow is projected in a way that prioritises one income stream over another (eg. invoice paid is more important that invoice due etc).  This means that in Wk1 there could be an invoice paid and one due so cell A1 needs to show the paid amount and cell A2 needs to show the due amount (etc).  I tried doing the equation longhand but the character length was over 12,000 and excels max characters in a formula is around 8,000 so the equation fell at the first hurdle.

This may be easier using VBA but I need the sheet to be adaptive so equations would be preferred.

As above, I've tried a long hand formula along with several staged IF formula but nothing is giving me the end requirement.

Comment: Sample data and desired output would be helpful here.

Comment: u may separate the equation into multiple cell .. instead of all in 1 cell..

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)